# How to find dy/dx = - fx/fy?

Tags: derivatives

I need some walkthrough in solving the following question:

```
find dy/dx = - fx/fy?
3x^2 - y^2 + x^3 = 0.
```

I need to know the method to solve this question.

According to my understanding what I have concluded that:

**1.** Take partial derivative of the question w.r.t. x.

**2.** Take partial derivative of the question w.r.t. y.

**3.** Put the values of both in the equation: -fx/fy and simplify.

**Like:**

```
fx = 6x + 3x^2
fy = -2y
-fx/fy = -(6x+3x^2)/(-2y) 
= (6x + 3x^2)/2y
```

I wanted to know if my conclusion is correct or there's something else which I am missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the differential of the given equation $3x^2-y^2+x^3=0$:

$$6x\,dx-2y\,dy+3x^2\,dx=0.$$

This gives you the requested derivative,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x+3x^2}{2y}.$$

Comment: So this means I have to prove that L.H.S = R.H.S.?

Comment: That's the solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is coming from total and implicit differentiation. Suppose that you have a function $$F(x,y)=0$$ then the total derivative write $$dF(x,y)=\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}dy=0$$ and what you want is $\frac{dy}{dx}$. So, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}}$$

In the example you give, you lost parentheses for the last expression.

Comment: I didn't still got it, Do I have to find Fx and Fy and then again the derivative of -Fx/Fy?